# Python: SMTPLIB and MIMETEXT Adding an attachment to an email

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, gmail

iv'e just started with these new modules in python and have been learing how to send an e-mail. I  can't find a solution on the web... How can I add an image/video attachment to this e-mail script?

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

abc = 'BLACK TITLE'
msg_content = '<h2>{title} <font color="green">TITLE HERE</font></h2>'.format(title=abc)
p1 = '<p>new line (paragraph 1)<\p>'
p2 = '<p>Image below soon hopefully...<\p>'

message = MIMEText((msg_content+p1+p2), 'html')

message['From'] = 'Sender Name <sender>'
message['To'] = 'Receiver Name <receiver>'
message['Cc'] = 'Receiver2 Name <>'
message['Subject'] = 'Python Test E-mail'
msg_full = message.as_string()

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login('sender', 'password')
server.sendmail('sender',['receiver', 'receiver'],msg_full)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Your answer is found [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include attachments, the email message should have a MIME type of multipart/mixed. You can create a multipart message using `email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart`.

You can send an image attachment like so:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

message = MIMEMultipart()

abc = 'BLACK TITLE'
msg_content = '<h2>{title} <font color="green">TITLE HERE</font></h2>'.format(title=abc)
p1 = '<p>new line (paragraph 1)<\p>'
p2 = '<p>Image below soon hopefully...<\p>'
message.attach(MIMEText((msg_content+p1+p2), 'html'))

with open('image.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
    message.attach(MIMEImage(image_file.read()))


message['From'] = sender
message['To'] = receiver
message['Subject'] = 'Python Test E-mail'
msg_full = message.as_string()

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(sender, password)
server.sendmail(sender,[receiver],msg_full)
server.quit()
```

If you want the pictures to be used in your HTML, they need to have a `Content-ID` header:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

message = MIMEMultipart('related')

msg_content = '''
<html><body><p><table><tr>
  <td>Hello,</td>
  <td><img src="cid:picture@example.com" width="150" height="150"></td>
  <td>world</td>
</tr></table></p></body></html>'''
message.attach(MIMEText((msg_content), 'html'))

with open('image.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
    image = MIMEImage(image_file.read())
image.add_header('Content-ID', '<picture@example.com>')
image.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename='image.jpg')
message.attach(image)


message['From'] = sender
message['To'] = receiver
message['Subject'] = 'Python Test E-mail'
msg_full = message.as_string()

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(sender, password)
server.sendmail(sender,[receiver],msg_full)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Unfortunately when the program is run with the sender and receiver data entered, the shell produces and error:     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\OneDrive\Documents\email test 2.py", line 15, in <module>
    message.attach(MIMEImage(image_file.read()))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\email\mime\image.py", line 43, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Could not guess image MIME subtype')
TypeError: Could not guess image MIME subtype

Comment: I have fixed the bug by editing the line     message.attach(MIMEImage(image_file.read(), _subtype="jpg")). Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. For the JPG file that I used, no `subtype` was required. Oh well. I'm glad it helped.